# How to add a common prefix to all variables in Stata 12

Tags: rename, stata

I have 100 variables in a .dta file and I would like to add a prefix "1" before each variable name. Looking at the documentation it looks like I have to use =. but that requires to specify which variables. How can I use that for all variables? Can anyone help me out? (Also the command "renpfix" has been superseded in STATA 12.)

EDIT: figured it out; the code is .ren _all (prefix)=

Comment: Please write an answer and mark as resolved. Look at this article: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record,

A numeral such as `1` would be illegal as the first character in a variable name.

There is nothing out of order in using `renpfix` in Stata 12. It's just an old command that does one of many things that the much more general `rename` can do, so it's flagged as out-of-date, but if you know the syntax, it will work so long as what you ask is legal. (As above a numeric prefix would not be legal.)

"Stata" is the correct spelling. Just as it would be wrong to write about programs in "c" or "JAVA", "STATA" is incorrect.